# Retrirar números float de uma string

Tags: c++

Eu tenho a seguinte string:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 3.56 1.5
```

Apenas os dois últimos números são números inteiros ou decimais, podendo ter cada um vários digitos.

Como posso fazer para guardar apenas os dois últimos números em 2 strings distintas?

Comment: O que você já fez? Qual sua dificuldade?

Comment: Você pode pegar alguma das soluções [desta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c) para fazer um `split` por espaço, colocar tudo dentro de um `array` e obter as posições `size - 1` e `size - 2`.